# How to use Overlay.modal in Qt5.10

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

The old overlay property is Obsoleted.

But how to use the new one in Qt5.10?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html

Comment: The docs provide an example, is not that enough?

Comment: I mean Overlay.modal

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Popup {
        id: popup
        width: 400
        height: 400
        modal: true
        visible: true

        Overlay.modal: Rectangle {
            color: "#aacfdbe7"
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation was lacking in that area, so it has now been updated with examples:

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/234224/

Comment: Thank you!!!! I tried everything to add this property to ApplicationWindow and failed. It works now. ： )